# What's the safest way to adjust my WinForms application main form starting size and position at run time?

Tags: c#, winforms

A WinForms application of mine makes serious use of screen area and would better be given as much as possible. At the same time I would not like to ignore small screen users. I also find it a bad manner to make an application to start in maximized mode by default. Moreover, I seek to deliver reasonable behavior without need to store and read configuration in files/registry.

So what I seek to do is to set the main form size at the application start time, setting it to something like `Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width * 85 / 100;` (and the same thing with height).

And this works but the problem is that the form bottom and right edges usually go beyond the screen in this case even though it is perfectly possible to fit the screen nicely if positioned properly.

What is the way to adjust the main form position effectively?

Comment: do you have a blockout image you could show (an image outlining the layout of the buttons etc)? this sounds a little bit like a ussability issue where there is too much happening on the screen at once

Comment: How about set this.startposition=manual; and then set this.position = new Point(0,0);

Comment: Or set `StartPosition` to `CenterScreen`?

Comment: This is it, @PoomrokcThe3years. `StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;` is what I have been missing, that's why my `Location = new Point(32, 32);` didn't work. Submit this as an answer and I will approve it as the solution.

Comment: While this question as stated is about implementation, it might be worth posting a similar question on ux.stackexchange.com to get feedback on the appropriate UI design solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you did not set the formposition.

First , Set

```
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

If you didn't set it , the this.locatin command won't ever work.

Next

```
    this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
```

It should works

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Location` to center the form based on the size you've chosen:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    this.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width * 85 / 100;
    this.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height * 85 / 100;
    this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width * 15 / 200, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height * 15 / 200);
}
```

Be sure `StartPosition` is set to manual.

Answer (score 1):

I usually attempt to load an application with the same position and size it had when it last run, with this information persisted in the registry.

There are a few complications in trying to do this - the screen resolution may have changed since the app last ran, etc.  To do so you might need to:

- handle SizeChanged and remember the size of the form whenever its WindowState is Normal (no point in remembering it when it's maximized or minimized.
- similarly remember its location whenever it's moved.
- persist this information when the app is closed
- on startup, use the persisted information to position and size the form, adjusted to ensure the whole form fits on the screen and has a sensible minimum size.

Comment: I would also persist if it was maximised when closed: on startup, open it maximised (but use the persisted size to set the "normal" size if they then do a rest.  As noted, you wouldn't persist the maximised size (so Restore).

Comment: @TripeHound - agreed, you could do that too.

Comment: We have used the same solution.  Whenever an app needs that much screen, I think it is very important to let the user decide what trade-offs they are willing to make based on their setup and the app should learn from that information.